# Woocommerce pay at the door shipping problem

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to cancel the fixed shipping in the woocommerce payment at the door. I looked for all the plugins and couldn't find it. In only 3 districts, my payment system is active at the door. When payment at the door is selected, I want to cancel the fixed shipping price of 20 TL. How can we do it?

thanks

True: 109,90 :(

[SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P39GF.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to WooCommerce-> settings->shipping->shipping zones, and deactivate the options you don't want to use. See more at [Woocommerce Documentation](https://woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-shipping-zones/)

Comment: fixed shipping will drop, I have no problem as countries :( It should be 109.90 but it puts +20 fixed cargo. When I choose payment at the door, I want the fixed shipping price to be :/